# xmlsec1 not found on ibm-cloud deployment

Tags: python, cloud, ibm-cloud, xmlsec1

I am having hard time to install a python lib called python3-saml

To narrow down the problem I created a very simple application on ibm-cloud and I can deploy it without any problem, but when I add as a requirement the lib python3-saml 
I got an exception saying:

pkgconfig.pkgconfig.PackageNotFoundError: xmlsec1 not found

The above was a deployment on ibm-cloud, but I did try to install the same python lib locally and I got the same error message, locally I can see that I have the xmlsec1 installed.

Any help on how to successfully deploy it on ibm-cloud using python3-saml?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define "deploy it". Is it Cloud Foundry, Cloud Function, Kubernetes, Virtual Machine, ...?

Comment: right, I was supposed to be more specific, it is a Cloud Foundry

Comment: Looks like the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169554/how-can-i-get-the-python-xmlsec-library-running-on-pivotal-cloud-foundry/52191751#52191751

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and I had to install the "xmlsec1-devel" on my CentOS system before installing the python package.

Comment: `libxmlsec1-dev` on debian-based systems.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy an app to Cloud Foundry on IBM Cloud (or other providers) you define the Python dependencies in a file **requirements.txt**. Check this [Cloud Foundry documentation on the Python buildpack](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/) for details on what to consider and where to place the files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't address the issue, the missing is a C application that I cannot install from the requirements.txt

Comment: @EdreiMarceloRibeiro - As a general rule, Python C applications are compiled when installed. This is not supported. You will either need to use a different library or prebuild the library yourself. Another tip. Use `virtualenv` when building apps to be deployed to other systems. You will then be able to use `pip freeze` to build the dependency list for `requirements.txt`.